# R: How can I annotate a ggplot with a text box?

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotate

I am looking to add a small white text box, with custom text in the body of my ggplot plot. The text I want to add is to identify a horizontal line I am adding to the plot.

```
  ggplot(cb_emp) +  
  geom_point(aes(x = grossunits, 
                 y = rate, 
                 color = as.factor(outlier))
                 , alpha = 1/4) +
  scale_color_discrete(name  ="Outcome",
                        breaks=c(0, 1),
                        labels=c("Not outlier", "Outlier")) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = meancbrate)) + 
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = meanac) +
  annotate("text", x = max(grossunits), y = meancbrate, label = "avg rate")
```

Here is the plot I get:

[image]

Here is the plot I want (or something like this):

[image]

Please let me know if there is an easy way of achieving this.

Greatly appreciate the help!

Comment: try `geom_label(x = max(grossunits), y = meancbrate, label = "avg rate")`

Comment: thanks for the quick reply @ahly! I tried it, however, I get no plot... it doesn't render. And, my R Studio instance hangs. Maybe it is trying to label all the points? I have about 25k points

Comment: calculate the x and y values where the label is to be displayed outside of the ggplot command. Then do something like `geom_label(x = x_lab, y = y_lab, label = "avg rate")`, where `x_lab` and `y_lab` refers to the position where you want the labels

Comment: geom_label seems to require as many labels as there are points so this does not work - annotate seems to be able to do this but does not provide and option for a box around the annotated text

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can simply change to

```
annotate("label", x = max(grossunits), y = meancbrate, label = "avg rate")
```

which will use `geom_label` rather than `geom_text` and so you get a rectangle around the label.

Comment: Any way to increase the font size of the text written by annotate?

Comment: Can probably add an argument `size = 7`